# 500v generation with 24V, request for current limitation

Tags: power-supply, power, high-voltage, switching

I am generating 500V from a 24V source. Attaching schematics. This circuit is generating stable 500V.

I am attaching a load of 7 kohm. In the schematics the buck regulator is supplying 19V to the transformer. What happens is at no load, the current sunk from buck converter is 0.6Amp, but at loaded condition the current becomes 3.2Amp and voltage of buck convertor drops to 2V and still the 500V output remains stable.

I need to limit the current because I am not allowed to sink 3.2Amp.

Please have a look at the schematics and suggest if there is any technique to reduce losses of this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Peak current limitation should work as long as input and output voltage remains the same. Good enough or do you need to limit the inrush behavior too? Do you softstart?

Comment: Is this a thermal issue from high RdsOn or a supply issue limiting current? Or ?

Comment: Just need to reduce current consumption actual supply that I am supposed to use can only supply 2.1 Amp. I have tested this circuit with 24V @ 5Amp supply. To use with actual supply I need to reduce it's current hunger.

Comment: What is the efficiency loss. And where? You have no specs for power

Comment: Issue is basically when I run this circuit with the 24V supply providing  1.2Amp the circuit never generates  500V But when I connect with the supply providing 5Amp it runs fine but the output of buck convertor drops to 2V and main input current shows 3.2Amp. I can provide whatever specs you guys need.

Comment: What exactly is the buck converter doing for you? Why can't you run the transformer directly from 24V?

Comment: Hang on- You have a load of 7K on the 500V, which is about 36W.  At the input of the flyback (say you have 85% efficiency, could be less) you will need 42W.  If the buck is 90% efficient your 24V input will have to supply 46.7W.  At 24V that's <2A.  If you're drawing 3.2A then your efficiency is way off.  Are you sure you're not saturating your transformer? (Coupled inductor actually).  And as @DaveTweed said, why do you need the buck converter?

Comment: I can not feed transformer with main power directly because when I do so then main power drops down and MCU shuts down.

Comment: Please explain with what frequency the FET switches? Which transformer is used? @Sidk

Comment: Why use an MCU instead of an SMPS chip?

Comment: How do you assemble your circuits? Which transistor do you use? How the transformer is made? What kind of bypass caps do you use? Without carefully-made PCB and fine selection of components you can't get any good efficiency.

Comment: That's a lot of DC in the transformer primary. If it's close to saturating, there goes your efficiency. Does its core get warm? Consider a classic push-pull design with 2 MOSFETs and a centre tapped primary.

Comment: Start everything from a blank sheet. Take a basis for the classic scheme and adapt it to their needs.

Comment: @AltAir Classic scheme of?

Comment: A classical or widely used circuit of a switched-mode power supply. For example, you do not have current feedback (resistor between source and ground of the FET). Also, the cause of using the MCU is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at what you are expecting.

You want about 35 W out at 500V.  That's 500V into a load of 7000 ohms.

Given 3.2 A at 24V, you are putting 77W in to get 35 W out.  Your efficiency is about 58%.

Your smaller power supply can 2.1A * 24V, so that's 50W going in.

But, wait.  You are reducing that to 19V so you've got closer to 40W going through the transformer.

Assume 45W to the transformer.  You would need an efficiency of at least 80% in the boost section to get your desired output.

That 80% needed efficiency is a long ways from the 58% you are getting.

Why are you introducing losses into the system by reducing the voltage going into the transformer?

Limiting the current is the wrong solution.

You need to be more efficient.

1. Lose the buck converter, drive the transformer directly from the 24V source.
2. Check the signal driving the FET.  If it has a slow rise time, you will lose power.
3. Ditch the 7805, and use a buck converter to power the processor.  The 7805 is throwing away power that could be going to the booster.  It may only be a couple of watts, but you seem to be pretty close to the edge with your power requirements.
4. Use a better FET.  Check the Rdson for 5V, and see if there are FETs available with a lower "on" resistance.
5. Your "schematic" shows no resistor between the processor and the FET.  That might cause ringing on the gate, which will also reduce your power output.

---

I'm no expert on switching power supplies - I have never built one.

The pointers above are based on the other questions about switching power supplies that I have read on this site.

If I have gotten something wrong, I hope someone will point out my mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for detailed suggestions, let me look into these points except 1. I'll update results here.

Comment: Power the processor temporarily from another source until you get your booster working.  That means:  lose that buck converter.  Improve your booster until it no longer clobbers your 24V supply.  At that point you can go back to powering the processor from the 24V.

Comment: Also, using a 5V output buck converter to power to processor gives you more "working space."  The 7805 requires around 7.5V in to provide 5V out.  A buck converter can deliver 5V out from much closer to 5V in.

Comment: @AltAir I am switching at 60KHz varying duty cycle from 5% to 50%.

Comment: Sorry I missed t mention in schematics I use TC4427V Gate Driver IC to drive mosfet with resistor on gate.

Comment: I took following steps and found respective results.
1-First I removed Buck Converter from transformer line and powered directly from 24V (5Amp) power supply (and I used seperate buck convertor to power up MCU).After power up I observed high current sink from power supply and it turned off and on again and again. Current going Up to 10A, it seemed buck conveter was maintaing constant current there by stablizing 500V.
2- Then I used another Buck convertor and that time current was 3.3Amp constant with 500V stable. I changed the current from POT on Buck module and got 2.0Amp sink from 24V.

Comment: 2- Then I used another Buck convertor and that time current was 3.3Amp constant with 500V stable. I changed the current from POT on Buck module and got 2.0Amp sink from 24V. 
3- Results in step 2 remained for long time again and again tested circuit worked perfect. But after few an hour I powered up it again shows 3.3Amp, I rotated POT again it again showed 2.0Amp but after I power cycle the circuit it shows 3.3Amp. I think I am missing something.

Comment: Follwoing are exact specs of the components in the cirucit.
1) Transformer Part No: COILCRAFT GA3459-AL
2) MOSFET Part No: FQP34N20 (Two in Parallel)
3) MOSFET Gate Driver IC Part No: TC4427V
4) Buck Converter IC: XL4016

Comment: Buck Convertor Link [Link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-CC-9A-300W-Step-Down-Buck-Converter-5-40V-To-1-2-35V-Power-module/32639621677.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.9.66154556FSgwNb&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536_10902,searchweb201603_6,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=3190a491-68e3-42f9-a087-7493befaea3c-1&algo_pvid=3190a491-68e3-42f9-a087-7493befaea3c&transAbTest=ae803_4)

Comment: Any comments please? I am stuck.

Comment: The information about the parts you used belongs in the question, with links to the datasheets.

Comment: Ain't no such beast as a Coilcraft "GA3459-AL."  There's a "GA3459-BL."

Comment: And add a **complete** circuit diagram instead of your block diagram.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Okay will be sharing the circuit in a while.

Comment: Do you have all the primaries properly in parallel?  They have to be connected in parallel, and the right way around.

Comment: yes all primaries are exactly parallel.

Comment: Hello all, thank you for such valuable suggestions. I was missing very important point basically. I monitored gate pulse and realized I need to Invert my PWM signal. And things worked COOL. Thanks all.