# 500V generation, MOSFET Heating Problem

Tags: high-voltage, circuit-protection, heatsink, overheat, damping-factor

Referring to my previous [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/430548/500v-generation-with-24v-request-for-current-limitation/430555?noredirect=1#comment1074762_430555). I have successfully generated 500V. The problem I am facing an issue. MOSFET I am using for switching is FQB34N20LTM. The MOSFET is burning badly. The snap of drain pulse is attached below. I have attached a good heatsink having fins as well but temperature never stops. Previously I made the prototype using breadboard and my circuit was cool, now I have made the PCB and it is burning. Please suggest me what should I do? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Getting shocked with 3 amps load at 500V is pretty dangerous even with DC if not potentially lethal

Comment: Not 3Amp load. I am generating 500V @ 70mA.

Comment: That is still a pretty hefty effect, just be careful and turn it off when working on it.

Comment: 500V at ~= 70 mA will kill you very easily. [Ive experienced 1200 VDC on one occasion - and was lucky to survive]. Not recommended.

Comment: FET must be rated >> 500 VDC (post link to datasheet please). Add a say 10V zener gate to source close to FET. Add maybe also a reverse biased small Schottky diode in same location. Use a smll resistor in gate drive. (3 - 10 Ohm range). Zener clamps induced gate spikes via Millar capacitance from drain. Schottky clamps negative 1/2 cycles of gate oscillations. Drive R helps damp gate oscillations.

Comment: What PWM frequency. What uC and what tyoe of pin / drive current. You MAY need a gate driver if fequency is other than very low. I can rovide a low cost simple circuit if of interest.

Comment: @Russell I am using Attiny and using PWM pin at 40KHz. As driver IC use TC4427. Yes please share anything that can help me out. This heating is destroying the design. Thanks again for help.

Comment: Are you already using the TC4227. You need to show a complete circuit of what you are doing. What did the Drain waveform look like on the breadboard. The oscillatory drain decay may well be OK. What does the gate waveform look like measured with probe tip at package gate and ground clip AT package source. | Is the FEt drain isolated from the heatsink electrically?  Can you provide a PCB layout image.

Comment: What is your driver Vdd? What is the voltage at the gate when driven? Datasheet says Vgsth = 2Vmax but they show no curve under 5V drive and give no data / graphs on  Id/Vds/Vgs characteristics which most manufacturers do. || OK - fig 2  - you MUST have the L part.

Comment: Is your FET definitely the ....L part. See fig 2 for https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQB34N20-D.PDF and https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQB34N20L-D.pdf The L part has a Vgsth of 1-2V and the non-L is 5V+ ish!!! .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have edited question including schematics and board layout, please check. And yes I am using 'L' part. Pulse on Micro-controller and at the gate of MOSFET is perfect PWM with no glitches and noise. The drain pulse is shown in the question.

Comment: Component values on cct diagram would be 'very useful' There are so many things that MAY make a difference. You seem to have a reasonable grasp of what you are doing so values are unlikely to be terrible but, as an example - the series R value with the Drain to V+ diode will affect what it does. As will the related Cap. The drain source snubber RC values likewise. ||| **** You say the drain pulse is shown. If it is you have a 700+V pulse at the output. If the mean is 500 VDC then you have quite a load somewhere.
Is your transformer "dotting" / polarity correct?

Comment: Thanks for response. First the RCD snubber shown in schematics is DNP. Transformer polarity is rechecked and is correct for sure. As you said "then you have quite a load somewhere" do you mean external load? or What?

Comment: You would expect 25 us between every mayor spike on the oscilloscope, but it’s roughly 16us. That’s like 62.5 kHz, instead of 40kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
As it worked in lashup mode these may well help.

- Add a say 10V zener gate to source close to FET.
- Add maybe also a reverse biased small Schottky diode in same location.
- Use a small resistor in gate drive. (3 - 10 Ohm range).

Zener clamps induced gate spikes via Millar capacitance from drain.
Schottky clamps negative 1/2 cycles of gate oscillations.
Drive R helps damp gate oscillations.

Report back.

What is the turns ratio?
FET must be rated >> [500 VDC / turns ratio]

[FET data sheet here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQB34N20L-D.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using 23 ohm at gate. I tried as you suggested both zener and schottkey. It works for 10 to 15 seconds after that my turns off and it is because somehow gate is opening continuously that increases the current sink. Please please suggest what should I do?

Comment: The turn ratio is 1:10. 1 being the primary side.

Comment: Are zener and Schottky on both FETs? | How if at all do waveforms differ between breadboard and PCB.

Comment: Yes on both FETs separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the gate waveform. From what I can see you are not driving it hard enough leaving it in the linear region to long causing it to dissipate more energy and thereby getting hot. If you are driving it with the pin of the MCU as shown in your first drawing that is not enough drive. Use a pair of NPN/PNP as an emitter follower driver. (Base to Base, Emitter to Emitter to gate, collectors to respective power rails. Place your zenior in the base side of the circuit.